# easy_install pip on Arduino Yun fails

Tags: arduino-yun, python, linux

I want to install `pip` on the Yún which is running **Linino OS** but every time I execute the standard steps for `opkg` i.e.

```
# opkg update
# opkg install distribute
# okpg install python-openssl
# easy_install pip
```

**Error**

```
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

What is the reason behind this?

**Kernel Information**

```
Linux Arduino 3.3.8 #1 Fri Nov 14 08:57:34 CET 2014 mips GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I think you mean: python setup.py install for your last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this Arduino Forum Thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=305052.0) helpful.

```
# wget \
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-6.0.8.tar.gz#md5=2332e6f97e75ded3bddde0ced01dbda3\
  --no-check-certificate
# easy_install pip-6.0.8.tar.gz
```

Apparently the [PyPi Package Site](https://pypi.python.org) is now **HTTPS** and hence `--no-check-certificate` option should be used. Also **MD5 Checksum** of the package needs to attached in the link in order to avoid a **HTTP 404 Error**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/pip-6.0.8.tar.gz
sudo tar xzvf pip-6.0.8.tar.gz
cd pip-6.0.8
python setup.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:`opkg update`  `opkg install python-pip`

## or python-pip3